# Ultrafilters arising from homomorphisms

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, set-theory, filters

Reading a paper from Bagaria and Magidor I stumbled upon a theorem which's probably well-known (but not to me at the time), the Łoś-Eda theorem. In the form stated:

> There exists a nontrivial group homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}^\kappa/\mathbb{Z}^{< \omega} \to \mathbb{Z}$ iff there's a $\omega_1$-complete non-principal ultrafilter on $\kappa$

It made me curious if there are other types of theorems recovering the existence of an ultrafilter from some homomorphism of structures like rings, groups etc. I tried doing a basic internet research but couldn't find much, only the opposite direction, that is, ultrafilters being applied to, but not extracted from.

What other theorems tell us that the existence of certain homomorphisms or relations between structures implies the existence of certain ultrafilters? I mean something algebraic and/or topological and non-obvious, so excluding embeddings of set-theoretic models, $\mathcal{P}(\kappa) \to 2$, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you count this as algebraic/topological, but Andreas Blass proved that the existence of an $\omega_1$-complete ultrafilter on $\kappa$ (i.e. the existence of a measurable cardinal) is equivalent to the existence of an exact endofunctor in the category $\mathbf{Sets}$ which is not naturally isomorphic to the identity endofunctor. See more details in the paper below:

*Blass, Andreas*, [**Exact functors and measurable cardinals**](https://doi.org/10.2140/pjm.1976.63.335), Pac. J. Math. 63, 335-346 (1976). [ZBL0348.18007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0348.18007).

Comment: Nice one, there's also some interesting characterizations for compactness as well mentioned  in [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20116098) by Takeuti.